# Dynamically creating a blade in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, content-management-system, laravel-8, laravel-blade

Im doing this project which I want to let the admin user to create custome pages for the website.

Is it possible to instead of saving users request in database, have a button in my createpage.blade.php that when user press it, it'll create a blade for me in views folder which holds users request?

P.S: also I want it to create a route in web.php but this one is not a matter of importance

Comment: What should be in the blade file?

Comment: Why don't you have a Page model with content attribute, and then store everything in the database, and load them dynamically. I mean I don't see the use for creating blade files, which needs to interact with the files system, also, altering web.php. Sorry , but you need to explain more.

Comment: the data I'll get from the user is html and css code, maybe even javascript(using a text editor like summernote and etc.). I doubt if reading that from data base would be safe. @Koussay

Comment: html, css and javascript. I'll accomplish that with a text editor such as summernote @mrhn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create page dynamically in Laravel by using `Storage::put()` method. Try this code:

```
$pageContent = "@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title', '".\Request::input('page_name')."')


@section('page-header')
    <h1>
        '".\Request::input('page_name')."'
    </h1>
@endsection

@section('content')
        
<div class='container'>
    '".\Request::input('page_content')."'
</div>

@endsection

@section('script')
    <script>

    </script>
@endsection

@section('style')
    <style>

    </style>
@endsection
";

$project_name = 'your_project_name';
\Storage::disk('disk_path')->put($project_name.'/resources/views/new-page.blade.php', $pageContent);
```

And add this disk to your filesystem.php under disks:

```
'disk_path' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => 'E:\xampp\htdocs',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

And use [`fopen()`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_fopen.asp) for write Routes in web.php

Answer (score 1):

So according to your need, You may use summernote or any WYSIWYG editor to write and store HTML/CSS/JS plain code in the database and then use one blade file to load the content and render it using this syntax on blade

```php
{!! !!}
```

But if it's user generated content, you must read this warning

> Be very careful when echoing content that is supplied by users of your application. You should typically use the escaped, double curly brace syntax to prevent XSS attacks when displaying user supplied data.

Update:
You may use third parties packages to protect your code
https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier

Further reading here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know there are packages for this

Comment: You may mark the question as answered. Thank you